# using two or more realtime query in one export function in firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way I can use two realtime database queries in one export function?

When I run this it works without errors:

```
exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    var totalKeys = 7;

    return admin.database()
        .ref('/messages')
        .orderByChild('id')
        .startAt(2)
        .limitToFirst(2)
        .once('value')
        .then(snap => { res.status(200).json({ total: totalKeys, date: snap.val() })
            return 1
        })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

but when I try to add the other query, it will trigger warnings on the CLI and it wouldn't show the total rows

```
exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/messages");
    ref.on("value", snapshot =>  { 
        var totalKeys = snapshot.numChildren(); }, 
        function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

    return admin.database()
        .ref('/messages')
        .orderByChild('id')
        .startAt(2)
        .limitToFirst(2)
        .once('value')
        .then(snap => { res.status(200).json({ total: totalKeys, datas: snap.val() })
            return 1
        })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

[image]

This is what I did about, I'm trying to get the total messages key and pass it into json data but it did't work

Comment: Where is the firebase part of the question?

Comment: What is your exact goal, because with return admin.database()
     .ref('/messages')
     .orderByChild('id')
     .startAt(2)
     .limitToFirst(2)
     .once('value') you should normally iterate over the two results. Other point: you should chain the promises.

Comment: my goal is to get the total messages length to able to calculate and use it as custom pagination

Comment: What is the aim of     return admin.database()
        .ref('/messages')
        .orderByChild('id')
        .startAt(2)
        .limitToFirst(2)
        .once('value')

Comment: it trigger error if i don't return it, this is my first time in firebase i'm just trying some tricks before i start implementing it into my app as backend

Answer (score 0):

I did it through this ugly way and it works perfectly but i still don't know where this warning in cmd is coming from around the count query
[image]

```
exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var returnArr = [];
      var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/messages");
      ref.on("value", snapshot =>  {
      returnArr.push(snapshot.numChildren());
  }, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

  return admin.database()
     .ref('/messages')
     .orderByChild('id')
     .startAt(2)
     .limitToFirst(2)
     .once('value')
     .then(snap => {
    res.status(200).json({ total: returnArr[0], datas: snap.val() })
    return 1
  }
          )
     .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```

This is the successfully json printout

```
{"total":8,"datas":{"
-L8llcB9-pdbQ9eTcQa_":{"id":2,"text":"4rg","uppercase":"4RG"},"
-L8llecNccSLyULtpw5R":{"id":3,"text":"omo","uppercase":"OMO"}}}
```

UPADATED

I finally accomplished what i were looking for!

Here is the code for realtime firebase database pagination function with json restful api

```
exports.testDbOp = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var returnArr = [];
if(req.query.page){
page_number = req.query.page;}
  else{
 page_number = 1;}
var item_per_page = 3;
      var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/messages");
      ref.on("value", snapshot =>  {
      returnArr.push(snapshot.numChildren());
  });
  var page_numberIncr = page_number;
var nextPosition = ++page_numberIncr;
var lastPosition = Math.ceil(returnArr[0] / item_per_page);
var position = ((page_number-1) * item_per_page);
  return admin.database()
     .ref('/messages')
     .orderByChild('id')
     .startAt(++position)
     .limitToFirst(item_per_page)
     .once('value')
     .then(snap => {
    res.status(200).json({ position: position, nextposition: nextPosition, lastposition: lastPosition, total: returnArr[0], datas: snap.val() })
    return 1
  }
          )
     .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
```